# How to properly set-up Graphviz for Polars on Mac or Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars, rust-polars

Polars has a powerful feature called `df.show_graph(optimized=True)`.

Have been trying to get this installed on my Windows and Mac computer, system info is below.

**Windows**
OS = Windows 10
Architecture = x86_64

**MacBook**
OS = Monterey
Arch= arm64 (Apple Sillicon M1 Mac)

---

Have installed `polars==0.13.40` and installed `graphviz==0.20`, including matplotlib. Additionally, have added GraphViz and Matplotlib (site-packages) to the PATH environment variable; but still, receive the below error message.

```
ImportError: Graphviz dot binary should be on your PATH and matplotlib should be installed to show graph.
```

Could someone please share a simple guide on how to set up Graphviz for Polars via Windows 10 or MacBook (with Apple Sillicon)?

Thanks
Jenobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common problem.
graphviz==0.20 is not the actual Graphviz package, it is a Python interface to the Graphviz package.  (For more info see https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ - "To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install Graphviz")
Go here to find Graphviz: https://graphviz.org/download/

Comment: Thanks after via conda installation, changing the python.exe executable path to conda's worked.